# File directory for Viber chat history on Mac OS (export chats to new Mac without backup)

Tags: backup

I have 2 questions:

- what's the directory and file name of a Viber messaging database so I can move it to a new device (for Intel based Macs)
- is there any way to move history from M1 to M2 device without creating a backup file on mobile device and then syncing with Mac

On old Mac devices, I could just copy Viber app onto a new device (same for media folder) and the history would auto upload onto new Mac. There was no need for mobile sync and cloud backups.

I then bought an M1 Macbook, but after having moved the Intel based Viber app, it opened empty. I tried moving M1 Viber app to M2 Mac and the damn thing opens with empty messaging history as well.

Please help. I really need to open an old file.

Edit: I just tried copying old Viber contents to an old Intel based Macbook with the same OS version, it opens with empty history. Why???

Comment: Have you considered the usual step of migrating from one Mac to another rather than trying [& failing] to copy everything manually?

Comment: I have an old history file that I need to open.

Comment: Google tells me it's called `viber.db`. You should be able to find it with [EasyFind](https://www.devontechnologies.com/apps/freeware) (freeware) if Spotlight can't find it. Google also thinks it's an SQL database.

Comment: I used Terminal, there is no viber.db on Mac. Maybe on Android or PC

Answer (score 2):

When I installed Viber on my Mac, it asked me whether I want to synchronize the history from the iPhone app. But if this won't help in your case, you could try to copy the old chat history from your previous Mac.

To find files related to Viber on your old Mac, you can run

```
find ~/Library -iname '*viber*'
```

At least on my Mac, this finds `viber.db` in `./Application Support/ViberPC/MOBILENUMBER/viber.db`.

Comment: so bizarre, I ran the command, it shows the same path, but when I go there, no ViberPC folder is present. So than I ran open from the Terminal to see if maybe it can open, it says the file does not exist.

Comment: @API If `find` finds the file, it's there :-) You did remember to use `Application\ Support` to protect the space character?

Comment: ah, thank you so much!

Comment: So I moved the files within the folder along with the viber.db file, but it still opens empty. I guess Viber made sure you can no longer keep the history unless you upload your messages to cloud huh? lol

Answer (score 0):

I was able to transfer Viber data between Macs in the following way

1. Run Viber on the new Mac
2. Backup created `config.db` file
3. Copy data from the old Mac and replace `config.db` from created backup

##### Step by step guide

We assume that we are working under the same user on the old and new Mac, otherwise we should take care about folders/files ownership.

**Old Mac**

1. Read all your messages and close Viber app
2. Create backups

   ```bash
   # Home folder is a base
   cd ~
   tar -cvz -f Viber-Profiles.tar.gz "Library/Application Support/ViberPC"
   tar -cvz -f Viber-Downloads.tar.gz Documents/ViberDownloads
   ```
3. Copy data to the new Mac

   ```bash
   # Copy to the new Mac user home folder
   scp Viber-Profiles.tar.gz Viber-Downloads.tar.gz user@192.168.1.10:
   ```

**New Mac**

1. Install, run and activate Viber on Desktop - [Set Up Viber on Your Desktop](https://help.viber.com/hc/en-us/articles/9084593040285)
2. Close Viber
3. Backup created config `config.db`

   ```bash
   # Home folder is a base
   cd ~
   cp "Library/Application Support/ViberPC/config.db" config.db.new
   ```
4. Remove created Viber folders

   ```bash
   # To exclude mixed files from Phone/PC
   rm -rf "Library/Application Support/ViberPC"
   rm -rf Documents/ViberDownloads
   ```
5. Unpack data from old Mac

   ```bash
   tar -xv -f Viber-Profiles.tar.gz
   tar -xv -f Viber-Downloads.tar.gz
   ```
6. Replace `config.db`

   ```bash
   cp config.db.new "Library/Application Support/ViberPC/config.db"
   ```
7. **Start Viber and you should be able to see all chats/messages/attachments**
8. Remove backups

   ```bash
   # And tar.gz on old Mac as well
   rm -f config.db.new Viber-Profiles.tar.gz Viber-Downloads.tar.gz
   ```